# $.post with two params in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

**Please refer below Scirpt code**

```
var criteriaSubmission = new Object();
        criteriaSubmission['CurrentController'] = "xx";
        criteriaSubmission['CurrentAction'] = "yy";
        criteriaSubmission['CurrentArea'] = "Cp";
var columIndex="[1,2,3,4]"

 var addModel = new Object();

$.post('Fav/Add', { addModel: criteriaSubmission, columns: JSON.stringify(columnsIndex) },
        function (data) {

        });
```

**MVC Action code:**

```
public ActionResult Add(SavedReportCriteriaModel addModel,string columns)
        {
//DO Something
    }
```

columns value are passed to controller action but addModel data is not passing. 
addModel value is coming as NULL.

**Model code:**

```
public class SavedReportCriteriaModel
    {

        public string CurrentController { get; set; }


        public string CurrentAction { get; set; }

public string CurrentArea { get; set; }
}
```

**i dont want to change the SavedReportCriteriaModel  to add another properties for columns. i need to have two params in action.**

why addModel is coming as NULL. what was the problem in jquery.post code ?

Comment: can you provide what is `OrganizationCriteriaModel`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it not valid javascript :-)

Comment: @Stephen that is simple way of passing.if more objects that time need specify all the properties explicitly.

Comment: Your already specifying them explicitly with `var criteriaSubmission = new Object() { criteriaSubmission['CurrentController'] = "xx"; .....}`

Comment: And do you really want `columns` to be `string` - its an array so wouldn't it make more sense to have the parameter as `string[] columns`? (which would mean using `$.ajax` with `traditional: true,` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 2):

why is this for:

```
var addModel = new Object();`
```

your `addModel` is a JSON property, and should be written in json as `{ "addModel" : ...` not assigning it to an object...

with just a simple mockup from your code, and fixing your type `columnsIndex` (as the property is called `columnIndex` (singular) I can pass all values to it:

[image]

the script page is as:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var criteriaSubmission = new Object();
    criteriaSubmission['CurrentController'] = "xx";
    criteriaSubmission['CurrentAction'] = "yy";
    criteriaSubmission['CurrentArea'] = "Cp";
    var columIndex = "[1,2,3,4]";

    //var addModel = new Object();

    $(function() {
        $.post('@(Url.Action("Add"))', {
            "addModel": criteriaSubmission,
            "columns": JSON.stringify(columIndex)
        },
        function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**To note:**

- `$(function() {})` that wraps the `$.post` call as it's important to only post when jQuery is fully loaded and page is ready
- `columsIndex` was emend to `columIndex` in the JSON data passed with the post
- `addModel` as a variable was commented out
- post URL is actually created using a MVC helper `@(Url.Action("Add")` this, in my demo site, will create a link as `/Home/Add` and I have added the `ActionResult` in the `Home` controller
- The JSON properties are wrapped in double quotes `"`

Comment: @balexandre, what mvc version you use?

Comment: 1. open chrome console (in Chrome press F12 and select "console") and see what javascript errors you have - 2. re-check the post URL

Comment: @balexandre am running in IE11

Comment: @Grundy as @Siva specified with a `tag`, I'm using MVC 3.

Comment: @balexandre it is triggering. data only  passing as Null. so it will not throw any error in console.

Comment: @SivaRajini this works on any browser, as a web developer, I'm used to the Chrome debug tools, that's all. Can you [join us on the Chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/828/q28499170), so we can help you with this, and not making this comment section a "chat"?